# xPages checkbox styling background image

Tags: css, xpages

How do I change checkbox style? I need especially to replace checked checkbox background/image..

Here is my xPage code:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/myCSS.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:checkBox text="Label" id="checkBox1" styleClass="mycheckbox">/xp:checkBox>
```

and here is CSS:

```
.mycheckbox:checked {
         background-color: green;
         box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px black inset;
         margin-bottom:2px;}
```

The problem is that when checkbox is checked it sets only border but not background color green. Same if I try to set and image for checked one.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css) might help

Comment: Please use the search function before making a new question, there are a lot of topics about this.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work on xPages app. I do want to keep current oneUI style for checkbox but for checked one I want to set my own style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a background color for checked checkbox. Even `!important` doesn't help.

You can workaround with JavaScript (toggle class on change event) or advanced CSS though.

With CSS, you can hide browser's default checkbox and replace it by a picture or "constructed" checkbox.

The following example is an adaption of the blog [Creating Custom Form Checkboxes and Radio Buttons with Just CSS!](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/)

XPage

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/myCSS.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:checkBox id="checkBox1" styleClass="checkbox" value="#{viewScope.test}"></xp:checkBox>
<xp:label id="label1" for="checkBox1"></xp:label>
<xp:label id="label2" for="checkBox1" value="Label"></xp:label>
```

myCSS.css

```
.checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox + label {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #cacece;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox + label:active, .checkbox:checked + label:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.checkbox:checked + label {
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    color: #white;
}

.checkbox:checked + label:after {
    content: '\2714';
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 3px;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using OneUI, you sometime have to force the override by using `!important`

I have ran across similar issues that I discuss in detail in this blog post I wrote:  http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2014/10/quick-tip-forcing-css-override.html

Note: CSS purists will frown on this practice, but they likely have never used OneUI.